# Conflict between plugin and existing jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

Separately, my jquery code works, and the downloaded plugin also. But when i try to fit them together (trying separate scripts in the header, same script in header/ body, external scripts separate/together..), just 1 or none of them work.

The plugin is called TinySlideshow (https://github.com/jhorstmann/TinySlideshow), the code inserted in the html script is the following:

```
<script>
 $('slideshow').style.display='none';
 $('wrapper').style.display='block';
 var slideshow=new TINY.slideshow("slideshow");
 window.onload=function(){
        slideshow.auto=true;
        slideshow.speed=5;
        slideshow.link="linkhover";
        slideshow.info="information";
        slideshow.thumbs="slider";
        slideshow.left="slideleft";
        slideshow.right="slideright";
        slideshow.scrollSpeed=4;
        slideshow.spacing=5;
        slideshow.active="#fff";
        slideshow.init("slideshow","image","imgprev","imgnext","imglink");
     }
    </script>
```

My question is, where do i have to include my `$(document).ready(function(){` in order to avoid conflicts with the plugin?

Comment: Your first two lines are not valid jQuery. `.style.display` is used for DOM elements, not jQuery objects.

Comment: And you're missing the `#` before the ID in the selectors.

Comment: Why ready handler would fix your issue? Providing error message if any will help you in order to get some answer

Comment: Please make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net "JSFiddle") with all relevant code.

Comment: That script comes from the jquery plugin which is exactly as i downloaded it, so even though i don't understand well how it works, i don't think it's wrong

Comment: You copied the sample script wrong. It has `$T('slideshow')`, not `$('slideshow')`.

Comment: @A. Wolff ready handler is not for fixing it, inside the ready it's the code that i want to put together with the plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$('slideshow').style.display='none';
$('wrapper').style.display='block';
```

to:

```
$T('slideshow').style.display='none';
$T('wrapper').style.display='block';
```

`$T` is a function in the TinySlideShow plugin that's just an abbreviation for `document.getElementById`.

You should either put all this code at the end or after the `<body>`, or put it all in the `$(document).ready()` handler.